# Python loop for Speech to text

Tags: python, loops

How to loop through below code so that out is generated constantly and displayed as output for a long speech through mic.

```
# import library
import speech_recognition as sr

# Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)

r = sr.Recognizer()

# Reading Microphone as source
# listening the speech and store in audio_text variable

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Talk")
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    print("Time over, thanks")
    # recoginize_() method will throw a request error if the API is unreachable, hence using exception handling

    try:
        # using google speech recognition
        print("Text: " + r.recognize_google(audio_text))
        #text1 = r.recognize_google(audio_text, language="te-IN")
        #print('Converting audio transcripts into text ...')
        print(text)
        #print(text1)
    except:
        print("Sorry, I did not get that")
```

Comment: for how much time your r.listen method listens right now? And when it ends listening, after a pause?

Comment: This kinda did the job, but it keeps listening and then type in the last few text and then listens and does the job, is there a way, I can improve by adding a timer (which I can play with) it listens then moves it to convert to text, but the listening has to happen and keep push the listening piece to a text loop and keeps doing this until there is a big silence. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

just add `while True` before the code. It will loop until you stop the script.

```python
# import library
import speech_recognition as sr

# Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)

r = sr.Recognizer()

# Reading Microphone as source
# listening the speech and store in audio_text variable

while True
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Talk")
        audio_text = r.listen(source)
        print("Time over, thanks")
        # recoginize_() method will throw a request error if the API is unreachable, hence using exception handling

        try:
            # using google speech recognition
            print("Text: " + r.recognize_google(audio_text))
            #text1 = r.recognize_google(audio_text, language="te-IN")
            #print('Converting audio transcripts into text ...')
            print(text)
            #print(text1)
        except:
            print("Sorry, I did not get that")
```

If you want to specify the repeat count, you can try this

```py
for repeat in range(100):
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
    ....
    repeat += 1
```

Your script will stop after 100 try.

Comment: The above syntax did not do what I thought it would do. It's more like a double loop with a parent loop that keeps listening to the main conversation/speech, but should be sending chucks of speech to convert to text and keep displaying the text on the screen, more like scrolling.

Comment: How to move audio_text = r.listen(source) to a string variable as the words are being spoken and do a count of the number of words in the new variable.

Comment: You may try to add `sleep(10)` time before `print("Time over, thanks")` You need to import sleep func. like that `from time import sleep`.